# How can I read the contents of a webpage, not the source code of that page?

Tags: java, html, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use translate.google.com/ to translate the string in Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412453/how-can-i-use-http-translate-google-com-to-translate-the-string-in-java-progr)

I want to read the contents of a webpage ,not the source code of that page.
Contents means some comment or some lines etc.
EX:
http://translate.google.com/#en|bn|I%20love%20life .

From this page, I want to collect the translated line "আমি জীবন ভালবাসি" 
How can I get this in JAVA ??

Comment: Good luck.  Google's translate API is a paid service, and they probably won't appreciate you going around it by scraping the site.

Comment: See also [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412453/how-can-i-use-http-translate-google-com-to-translate-the-string-in-java-progr) by this user, to save yourself saying what they have already been told before, and recently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I see he hasn't learned.  FYI justlife, Google is usually pretty good at identifying programmatic behavior.

Comment: @climbage *"Google is usually pretty good at identifying programmatic behavior."*  Good point, I don't recall that coming up in the previous thread.  I got stuck on "Don't thieve!" & the OP was doing their best to ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

but you do want to read the contents of the source code, as it contains the content your looking for..

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="bn"><span class="hps">আমি</span></span>
```

this is the node that contains the content of the translation...if you can build the url containing the un translated string, capture the response to that url and then find #result_box, you will have your content

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with [`HtmlUnit`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). Look at the method [`DomNode#asText()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#asText%28%29).